# php - sqlsrv encoding

Tags: php

My Project builds on PHP and connect to MS SQL Server. I am using sqlsrv library. The fields type in MS SQL is nvarchar. When I define the parameters for connection I also put "utf8". It is:

```
global $cnf;
$cnf = array();
$cnf["mssql_user"]  = "xxx";
$cnf["mssql_host"]  = "xxx";
$cnf["mssql_pw"]    = "xxx";
$cnf["mssql_db"]    = "xxx";
$cnf["CharacterSet"]    = "**UTF-8**";
```

When Insert records to database, for Vietnamese content and Chinese content I use:

```
$city = iconv('UTF-8', 'utf-16le', $post['city']);
$params = array(array($city, null, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY)));
$sql= "INSERT INTO tblCityGarden (city) VALUES(?)
$stmt   = sqlsrv_query( $this->dbhandle, $sql, $params);
```

It inserts data OK for Vietnamese and Chinese language (the data stored in database for Vietnamese and Chinese is correct).

However when I load the records back into web, It appears the strange character (?, �).
I try some php as iconv, mb_detect_encoding, mb_convert_encoding and search many results on internet, but It cannot work. How can I display correct data

Please someone who has experiences about this issues

Comment: Have you tried using two different connection arrays to insert each of the two encoding types? So a UTF-8 connection for your standard inserts, then a separate utf-16le connection for the Chinese and Vietnamese inserts?

Comment: Just noticed this is an old post (hehe)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem (�), but with single quotes, double qoutes, and "Rights Reserved" characters... Here is what I've found:

- The `CharacterSet` specified seems to "rule all", so what you set this to will determine the encoding for the connection (as it should). I did not have ANY `CharacterSet` configured on my connection(s). Simply setting this resolved my issue, along with making sure that the values that were inserted into my DB were not double encoded via `htmlspecialchars()`.
- header()'s must be set before ANY output (this is really important)
- headers cannot be set to something different later in the document
- Sometimes trailing spaces before and/or after the closing `?>` in your PHP file can cause issues (I don't use this closing tag, but I saw this mentioned a lot while searching)

I am not familiar with `iconv()`, and I am most certainly not experienced with encoding in general, but I solved my issue just by taking the time to check my headers and ensure they meet the above standards...

Your query parameters also look strange:
`$params = array(array($city, null, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY)));`

I have not seen a multidimensional array passed into that argument... (just a note)

Comment: Funny thing is ordinary htmlspecialchars() fixed my hours of troubleshooting. For everyone, if sqlsrv_query() or mssql_query() is causing some special character to be missing in my case `<` try wrapping the result of the rows in that powerful function.

I did 
`foreach($row as $key => $value) {
   if(is_string($value)) {
      $row[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
    }
}`

Comment: @Temitayo - I'm glad you were able to resolve your issues! I wasn't so lucky... If I remember correctly, I had accidentally performed `htmlspecialchars( $value )` twice. So, basically, I had `htmlspecialchars( htmlspecialchars( $value ) )` being performed on my values... I believe this was a big part of me arriving at this thread.